# Is there a name for a $2 \times 1$ rectangle?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Certain types of triangles and quadrilaterals have acquired special names; for example, the *drafter* triangle ($30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$), the *golden* rectangle ($\phi\times1$), the *lozenge* (rhombus in which the acute angles are $45^\circ$), and so on.

Has a special name been given to the $2\times1$ rectangle?

Comment: Domino? This was then reinterpreted to create tromino, tetromino, pentomino,... and [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino).

Comment: A domino? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_(mathematics) These names are not particularly widely used or interesting to mathematicians, so that may explain the downvotes.

Comment: domino was also my first thought ...

Comment: Ah yes, domino! Thanks!

Comment: @preferred_anon - [185 maths papers at Arxiv.org contain the words "domino" and "tile"](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=domino&terms-0-field=all&terms-1-operator=AND&terms-1-term=tile&terms-1-field=all&classification-mathematics=y).

Comment: @tell I suppose I mean that in most cases where somebody needs to use such an object, they will just make up a name. Domino is commonly used in the context of polyomino tiling, and it is a common enough object that most people know what you're talking about. But sometimes the search for a special name just results in an obscure title nobody really recognises. (the "silver" and "bronze" ratios are good examples)